# Command via SSH does not work

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I am trying to connect to SSH Session of Windows (via Cygwin) from AIX LPAR, but could not make the following command to work

```
ssh XYZ@MACHINE1 'df -h /e'    
df: illegal option 'h'
usage: df [-akiPt] [-Fw] [-T type] [file | file_system ...]
```

Output (when I executed from host itself)

```
$ df -h /e
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
e:                     87G   81G  6.4G  93% /e
```

I understand when I execute the command from AIX LPAR binary 'df' was picked up from AIX.

As I SSHed, I want to run the command on that machine and see the output

Comment: Try running `which df` in both ssh and the host itself. Specify the full path to `df` in ssh.

Comment: @choroba  'df' binary exists on /usr/bin on both AIX and Cygwin.   However "ssh XYZ@MACHINE1 '/usr/bin/df -h'" yielded the required output.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Which shell and which type of quotation mark are you using ? The problem seems on client side not cygwin one.